# Disabling smartypants' dash conversion

Tags: python-sphinx

In general I want to use smartypants to convert straight quotes, and `--` into en-dashes, etc. But occasionally I want two hyphens, **not** in a literal string (between backticks) I tried with `-\-` or `-\ -`, but it still gets converted into an en-dash. Is there any way I can force two consecutive hyphens without disabling smartypants? (It must work inside inline formatting, by the way).

Example:

```
Some times I want an en-dash -- like here -- but not when
I must explicitly write **two hyphens (--)**
```

The last `--` should stay as is.

Answer (score 0):

Use a backslash:

```
\--
```

0123456789